# Fundamental covers

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, product-space

A simple question. Suppose $\{U_{\alpha}\}_{\alpha \in A} $ is a fundamental cover of $X$, that is $V \subset X$ is open if (and only if) $V \cap U_{\alpha} $ is open in $U_{\alpha}$ for all $\alpha \in A$. Take a space $Y$, that you can assume to be compact. Is $\{ U_{\alpha} \times Y\}_{\alpha \in A } $ a fundamental cover of $X \times Y$ ?

I think the answer is "yes". You can also assume that $X,Y$ are metric spaces if you wish to.

Comment: Where did you get this definition of a "*fundamental cover*" from? Any family $U_\alpha$ of open sets that cover $X$ satisfies your definition. So ,presumably, the interesting cases are when some of the $U_\alpha$ are not open.

Comment: Exactly. The two important cases of fundamental cover are open covers and locally finite closed covers. A fundamental cover is what you need to test the continuity of a function locally. The definition is taken from Manetti, Topology